# "cheap-ass" option StackOverflow Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, students

Thank you for making the listing option free for students, but the penalty sucks.  There's a big blue **student** on the top right of [my CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ajh).

Had I known that was the penalty, I wouldn't have signed up as a student at all.  I don't see a way to "revoke" my subscription and remove the banner; I'm not exactly thrilled about that.

Also, you're likely going to have non-students choosing that option to get a free listing for a year.  If the penalty is a big, ugly banner for free listing anyhow, why not make a "cheap-ass" option to get free listing for a year, and allow the cheap-ass population to at least be honest with you?  Then put a huge ugly banner on their resume that says "cheap-ass".

I am a student, but I'd rather have a big "cheap-ass" banner on my resume than deal with the stigma of being "just a student".

Comment: Someone call the whambulance...

Comment: People don't understand the value of a good career marketplace. Pay $99 for it, and if it nets you a job in 12 months, then your first day of work will likely recover the cost of the subscription. It's certainly a no-brainer at the beta rate of $30/3 years. And yet people not only lie to get a valuable listing for free, they then have the gall to complain about the free product that they lied in order to get in the first place.

Comment: If your looking for "cheap-ass", I am afraid this is going to be closed as "Not StackOverflow Related"

Comment: http://xkcd.com/37/

Comment: He didn't say he wasn't a student, nor is there any indication that he lied.  He's just saying that he doesn't like the banner, which doesn't seem unreasonable, especially since the implication is that he would have paid full price had he known about the banner's existence.

Comment: He's implying it

Comment: @Juan: How is he implying he isn't a student?  His last paragraph starts very clearly with "I am a student".

Comment: He says right in the last sentence, "I am a student" - now if you dig further you find he graduated with honors with what appears to be an associates degree in 2007.  Further, he appears to be keeping up with the class schedules of his local college.  I no longer doubt that he is a student, but he's also indicating that he has a current job, which indicates to me that he's capable of paying for it, but would like a cheaper option without any strings attached.

Comment: It doesn't matter though.  His complaint isn't affected by whether he's a student or not.  His complaint is that they force him to include a big blue "STUDENT" badge very visible above his CV, they didn't disclose this prior to checking the student-free version, and there's no easy/obvious way to undo it.  It's a valid complaint.

Comment: Instead of complaining, why don't one of you clever 2000+ rep editors re-phrase the question instead if jumping on your own "whambulances"? Also read the last part of the post: *"I am a student, but I'd rather have a big "cheap-ass" banner on my resume than deal with the stigma of being "just a student"."* Doesn't say he's trying to free-load.

Comment: But it's silly to complain about a free meal.  You eat it, or you don't.  Whining that you didn't realize the dinner plate was going to be bright blue, thus signifying to everyone else in the dining room that you opted for the free meal is counterproductive.  I certainly don't see the reasoning behind changing the color of the plate to yellow-cheap from blue-student, as if that is better.  Chances are good he doesn't want to be confused with a 20-something whippersnapper with no real life experience, but still wants to get the benefits the 20-something whippersnappers get.

Comment: But it's not just a free meal.  If you go into a restaurant, and the guy says "hey, you're cool, want your meal free", would you say no?  Nah, you'd say "sure, that sounds great".  Then the waiter yells "OKAY, THIS CHEAP GUY WANTS A FREE MEAL!" as he goes to get it for you.  That's all well and good, if you know that's what's going to happen, but you'd like to know beforehand so you can say, "nah, I think I'll just pay for my meal."

Comment: (Basically, I'm just agreeing with your prior comment...as long as  he can change to a paid account and be rid of the banner, there's just no issue. I imagine that many people would willing to take advantage of that...win-win.)

Comment: @Adam Davis: how do you know my class schedule, exactly?  Yes, I have a job. I'm sure many will agree that "can afford" does not necessarily follow from "is employed".  Hence my CV.  Hence this discussion.  Now, about that cheap ass-option ...

Comment: @drfloob - sorry to go all internet creepy stalker on you - I don't know your schedule, only that you keep up with the registration schedule - your website (linked in your profile) has a calender utility in python on the front page to alert you of the college's schedule.  Can afford does not follow from is employed, but sadly it is one of the few ways to determine how serious someone is about their job search without a long process - put your money where your mouth is, so to speak.

Comment: Keep in mind that the service's stated purpose is to hook REALLY REALLY REALLY good programmers up with REALLY REALLY REALLY good jobs.  If you are in a job where you can't afford a $99/yr job service, then one *might_ argue that you aren't a "really really really" good programmer...  There is a correlation between ability and pay, where "good" is not defined solely as programming skill, but overall candidate quality.

Comment: @Adam *"If you are in a job where you can't afford a $99/yr job service, then one might argue that you aren't a "really really really" good programmer.."* - oh dude...that's such a bad argument.... in the current economic climate there are lots of REALLY REALLY REALLY good programmers out there and very few REALLY REALLY REALLY good jobs. Over here where I am, the contract market has dried up, the banks have gone bust and there ain't a lot going on. In 2002 I was made redundant just when the last of the .COM outfits crumbled in Edinburgh. The jobs market was awash with great people.

Comment: That's undoubtedly true - which is why I hedged my point with "might."

Comment: I don't see how how much you can afford is relevant to the discussion.  I haven't seen many people saying they can't afford it...certainly the original question didn't say that.  Free is generally considered better, all other things being equal...why *wouldn't* someone take a free option, if it is equally good?  Of course, then they discover it's not equally good...and that's the problem.  It's not that they couldn't afford the $99...but no one adaquately explained the difference in service ahead of time.  (It could be this user just missed the obvious, or it could be not well documented.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to participate in Careers, but you don't want to pay for it.  I don't think that's going to fly for a number of reasons, primarily due to the cost increasing the quality of the pool of candidates by only including those who are actively searching.

The student option recognizes the fact that many students don't have the money to pay for such a service, and gives them a free year.

Beyond that, though, you should recognize that $99 will be recovered in your first day of your new job, so it's certainly worth the cost.

A "cheap" option merely serves to dilute the pool of candidates with those that really aren't interested in changing their job proactively.  Keep in mind that the existing free CV options still allows the public CV viewing, it just doesn't open you up to employer searches.

Contact the careers administrators - they've converted student accounts into paid accounts before, and will likely do so again.

Comment: +1 for the research... That even makes it better!

Comment: @Adam: I think you're close...I think he's saying that he is a student, but doesn't want to be so obviously labeled as such...to the point where, despite the discount he could legally get for being a student, he would have refused it and paid full price to avoid the banner.  I didn't get the impression he wanted to lie about his status, but didn't want it to be the first thing that people would see, either.  I think he's (justifiably) worried that recruiters, after they get used to the site, will use the big "student" banner as a "skip" option, and never get any further into the cv.

Comment: Sorry Adam, downvoted on this one for conclusion jumping...see Beska's comment above and *"I am a student, but I'd rather have a big "cheap-ass" banner on my resume than deal with the stigma of being "just a student".*

Comment: No need to apologize, and I appreciate the comment.  I suppose I can edit my post down further...

Answer (score 6):

> why not make a "cheap-ass" option to
>   get free listing for a year

Since when is free ***not*** cheap? If you are a student, what is the issue with it saying as such. You ARE a student, so what is the issue?

And what stigma is there for being a student? To some degree, employers today like students because they can hire them cheaper than others.  So I would actually consider it to be an advantage.

Now if you are a graduate student, yet working full time, maybe the banner could say:

> Graduate Student - Working Full Time,
>   but still too cheap to buy a 3 year
>   subscription

There should be a way at some point to move away from a student account into a paid account.  Considering this is all rather new, I'm guessing that will be introduced someday if it is not already there.

Answer (score 6):

I agree there should be a way to "un-student" yourself if you're willing to pay and perhaps a better explanation upfront about what saying you're a student will do. However, to your larger point, I believe the "I'm cheap" option would undermine the paid option in a way to student option will not, since you can only get one free year by saying you're a student. There has to be value added for paying for the service or no one will do it.

Comment: The real value in a paid service is that it gets rid of a significant number of people who really aren't searching for a job actively, or who aren't serious about changing jobs.  If it's not worth the fee to you, then get out of the pool and leave it open for those that are serious about it.  It benefits both the candidate and employer.

Comment: Easy +1 for the first sentence.  That sounds like it would solve the entire issue.

Comment: (and I think the "cheap-ass" option he's suggesting is tongue-in-cheek, though I could be wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if I were an employer and I found out that you were masquerading behind the "Student" option to save money when you're not a student, the first thing I would do is not hire you.  Honesty is big.

If you're a student, great, there's nothing wrong with that.  In fact, a lot of people see that as a plus especially if you are going to graduate school.  Sure some employers are going to actively not look at student resumes, but really, do you want to work for them anyway? I would guess probably not.  I would think the "cheap" option on your resume would be a much bigger stigma than student.  To me, student says, "I want to learn and I am spending my time and money to do so."  Cheap says: "I spend too much money on cheetos to afford this."

Comment: You mentioned "masquerading behind the Student option" and you also said that "Honesty is big."  So, although you don't want to hire someone who is a "cheap-a##", you should be able to respect what the original post-writer said about "allow[ing] the cheap-ass population to at least be honest with you".  In other words, what the original post advocates would also help YOU with what YOU advocate, which is avoiding duplicitous folk AND avoiding cheap folk.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the site should lose revenue, because people don't want to pay minuscule amount of money.  Isn't that what dice and monster are for?  What I'm saying is that under no circumstances would I hire someone how tries to be dishonest, because they can't float the 100 dollars a year to get a 50-100k job.  Seriously, that works out to what 8 bucks a month?  I spend more than that on coffee.  The cheap population wants to be honest, here's a thought don't post on careers.  That's being cheap and honest, but that's not what people want is it.

Comment: Who out there cannot get 100 dollars ready to make an investment in their career?